# Node.js, Express, MySQL - update schema

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have a small app running on a production server. In the next update the db schema will change; this means the production database schema will need to change and there will need to be some data manipulation.

What's the best way to do this? I.E run a one off script to complete these tasks when I deploy to the production server?

Stack:
Nodejs
Expressjs
MySQL using node mysql
Codeship
Elasticbeanstalk

Thanks!

Comment: *"I.E run a one off script to complete these tasks when I deploy to the production server"* that's usually a good option, just make sure part of said script involves creating a backup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The best way" depends on your circumstances. Is this a rather seldom occurrence, or is it likely to happen on a regular basis? How many production servers are there? Are there other environments, e.g. for integration tests, staging etc.? Do your developers have an own DB environment on their machines? Does your process involve continuous integration?

The more complex your landscape is, the better it is to use solutions like Todd R suggested (Liquibase, Flywaydb).

If you just have one production server and it can be down for maintenance for a few hours, the it could be sufficient to

1. Schedule a maintenance downtime with your stakeholders and users
2. Shutdown the server
3. Create a backup
4. Update the database structure and contents as necessary
5. Deploy software updates
6. Restart the server
7. Test the result (manually or automatically)
8. Inform your stakeholders and users

If anything goes wrong, rollback to a backed up version of the database and your software.

Having database update scripts is advisable. Having tested them once or more is advisable even more. Creating a backup in advance is essential.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.liquibase.org/ or http://flywaydb.org/ - pretty "heavy" for one time use, but if you'll need to change the schema again in the future, probably worth investing the time to learn one of these.